# Any alternative way to copy specific file from private git repository to remote server with Ansible without ssh

Tags: git, ansible, copy, gitlab

My question is that I want to copy a specific file from private git repository to remote server with ansible but I don't want to use ssh key. Do you know any alternative way like such as with api key? Like below code sample Im getting permission issue, so I want to add api key or sth else to get repo file.

```
---
- name: Sample
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: true
  tasks:
   - name: Copy
     become: yes
     git:
        repo: 'https://gitlab.com/sample-project/branch-a/sample.xml'
        dest: "/home/sample-file"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

- a deploy token, see [Gitlab access token for a single project or group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57067748/gitlab-access-token-for-a-single-project-or-group/57070666#57070666)
- in URL credentials, see [How do I pass username and password while using Ansible Git module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841914/how-do-i-pass-username-and-password-while-using-ansible-git-module)
- If you are using Gitlab CI, masked environment variables to store the token could be useful, see [masked-variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#masked-variables). Else, a vaulted variable see [vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html).

```
---
- name: Sample
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: true
  tasks:
   - name: Copy
     become: yes
     git: 
       repo: "https://{{ username| urlencode }}:{{ deploy_token | urlencode }}@gitlab.com/sample-project/branch-a/sample.xml"
       dest: /home/sample-file
```

Comment: So when I try to run with like `repo: "https://userA:sampleUBFuhb24hfagb48234@gitlab.com/sample-project/branch-a/sample.xml"` Im getting error now like this **\nfatal: unable to update url base from redirection:** Did I write correct syntax for the username and token?

Comment: That error means the part after the @ is not understood as a valid repo. Try using `version: branch-a` to specify the branch, or switch to a `command: git archive ...` task instead of `git: ...` since you need a single file.

Comment: edited after @gitlab part and it works now, thank you.