# How to install gitlab-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitlab

I am trying to create a group access token for Gitlab project. It requires the access to gitlab-rails console to do it. On gitlab tutorial, this is the link to install it: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/operations/rails_console.html

As I tried both Omnibus installations and installation from source. Here is what it says:

For Omnibus installations

`sudo gitlab-rails console` gives error:

`sudo: gitlab-rails: command not found`

For installations from source

`sudo -u git -H bundle exec rails console -e production` gives error:

`sudo: unknown user: git`

`sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit`

I couldn't find any other tutorial or forum on how to install `gitlab-rails` command.

Comment: The Rails console is for GitLab system administrators. Do you have a Gitlab server? If yes, u need to start rails console, u dont need to install it.

Comment: My gitlab account was created by my group project . I am not sure if I have gitlab server. Is there a way to verify it? Sorry if this question is silly.

Comment: If you are an administrator of a self-managed GitLab instance, you can create a group access token in the Rails console. I dont think u are GitLab system administrators. Because you don't know if you have a server or not. Contact Your Project owner for more details.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do, but it clearly requires administrator. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html#group-access-tokens

Answer (score 1):

> It requires the access to gitlab-rails console to do it.

This is no longer the case:

See [GitLab 14.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/01/22/gitlab-14-7-released/#group-access-tokens) (January 2022)

> ### Group access tokens
>
> With group access tokens, you can use a single token to perform actions for groups, manage the projects within the group, and, in GitLab 14.2 and later, authenticate with Git over HTTPS.
>
> **Previously, group access tokens were limited to self-managed instances only, and could only be generated using the Rails console**.
>
> **Now, you can create group access tokens using the UI and API**.
>
> You can define token name, expiration date, and scope. You can also revoke an existing group access token.
>
> Thank you [Fabio Huser](https://gitlab.com/fh1ch) for your contribution!
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_7/group_access_token.png -- Group access tokens]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/settings/group_access_tokens.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/214046).

Comment: great that gitlab keeps improving